# Create directory tree based on map array

Tags: php, iterator

My task is to create a directory tree where some directory files need to be filtered.
I think it's a good idea to create a map where I can specify, for each directory, whether to apply filtering.

```
protected $templatesMap = array(
    'config' => true,
    'html' => [
        'pages' => false,
        'header' => true,
        'index' => false,
        'main' => true,
        'product' => true,
        'reviews' => false,
    ],
    'html_mobile' => [
        'banner' => true,
        'pages' => false
    ]
);
```

Here is my code:

```
protected function getDirectoriesTree()
{
    $templateTree = array();
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('design/theme_dir_name/'), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
    /** @var RecursiveDirectoryIterator $fileInfo */
    foreach ($iterator as $fileInfo) {
        $path = $fileInfo->isDir() ? array($fileInfo->getFilename() => array()) : array($fileInfo->getFilename());
        for ($depth = $iterator->getDepth() - 1; $depth >= 0; $depth--) {
            $dirName = $iterator->getSubIterator($depth)->current()->getFilename();
            if (!in_array($dirName, ['.', '..'])) {
                /**
                 * 
                 * My problem is here! 
                 * I do not know, how to check that if file must be filtered or not, 
                 * based on $this->templatesMap.
                 * 
                 */
                $path = [$dirName => $path];
            }
        }
        $templateTree = array_merge_recursive($templateTree, $path);
    }
    return $templateTree;
}
```

Please, help me make check target item of map on each iteration. Or if is a bad idea, what is alternative way?